# Is it possible to view two files simultaneously in Geany?

Tags: text-editing, ide, geany

I tend to be a simple text editor user, but when I want IDE-like features, I've been using Geany.  One thing I find bothersome about it, though, is I can see only one file at a time.  Sometimes I want to edit a .cpp file while looking at a .hpp file (or two) without flipping back and forth trying to memorize code.

(Of course the easy answer is to try a different IDE, but if I want to stick with geany for some good reason...then what?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Split Window plugin will allow you to have one document in one pane and switch between files in the other.

Comment: It is also a way to get a menu of the currently open documents (without having to use the left side bar).

Comment: There are lots of things that don't work in the split window: search, for example. Also, if you make changes in it, and there is a different file open in the primary window that also has changes, if you save while editing the second window, it is the file in the primary window that will be saved. So if you want to work on two files at the same time, the other answer - the simple workaround of having two instances open side by side - is safer and works best.

Answer (score 3):

You can open two instances of Geany, i.e. two different windows, and put them side by side with whatever documents you want. This is what I do.

Comment: Because what you can do in a split window (using the Split Window plugin) is so limited, for many purposes this is the best option.

Comment: Just a PSA for others confused by this--when you open a second instance of Geany, any configuration changes can be overwritten by the other instances. It seems to keep a full copy of the configuration in memory, and writes it out no matter what. So the last window closed "wins." This is my only point of friction with this editor so far.